# Optimization problem / Derivative of matrix Confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have attached a small snippet from my lecture notes where we are dealing with constrained optimization. $E,C$ are matrices.

I am confused with Eq. (4.12) as to how they have differentiated with respect to $E$ when $E^T$ is present. Then, I do not know how they get from Eq. (4.12) to Eq. (4.13).
[image]

Comment: Are $C, E$ symmetric matrices?

Comment: have you computed the derivative of (4.10) with respect to $E_{ij}$?

Comment: @Cesareo E is a rotation matrix, so it is not symmetric in general. However, C is symmetric.

Comment: @LinAlg I tried this, but I do not know how to re-write the first term so that it is a scalar.

Comment: You should update the question to add relevant information on $C$, $E$, etc.

Comment: There is some pdf on this on the internet. Matrix calculus cookbook or some such https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf page 10.

Comment: @mathreadler that is repeating the answer. The question is about the 'why'. I wonder if $E$ is perhaps a vector, since $E^TE$ and $1$ have the same dimensions (see 4.10).

Comment: @linalg I know this. It is why I wrote comment and not answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that $C$ is symmetric.

Let $\phi(E) = E^T CE -\lambda E^T E$, then
$\phi(E+H) = \phi(E)+H^TCE+ E^TCH -\lambda H^T E-\lambda E^T H  +r(H)$, where
$\|r(H)\| \le K \|H\|^2$.

Then $D \phi(E)H = H^T(CE - \lambda E) + ( CE - \lambda E)^T H$.

Suppose $D \phi(E)(H) = 0$ for all $H$, then choose $H=CE - \lambda E$ to get
$2 (CE - \lambda E)^T (CE - \lambda E) = 0$ from which we get
$CE - \lambda E = 0$ (since $A=0$ **iff** $A^TA = 0$).

I believe the derivation given in the question is incorrect, or at least misleading.

Comment: For a bonus point: have you found a minimum or a maximum?

Comment: @LinAlg: I would need to know what the optimisation problem is first... Most Lagrangians I have encountered are scalar valued :-).

Comment: A Google search on "the variance (4.7) can be maximized" reveals a background of principal component analysis. $C$ is a covariance matrix, and the constraint is $E^TE = 1$. I agree that minimizing a matrix valued function is odd at least.